# Express post request gives {}

Tags: node.js, api, express, post

So, when i make a Post request to the ExpressJS api with postman (localhost:8080?test=test), i should get this from the api: {test: test} or something right? But i get this: {}.

Heres my code:
Api:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../../src/'));

app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log('Running...');
})

app.post('/', function(req,res){
    let data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data)
})
```

Can you help me?

Edit:
[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPjK5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside post endpoint you are console logging req.body which is actually `{}`. According to the endpoint you are receiving data as query params. Therefore you have to use `req.query` instead of `req.body` to capture the data.

Comment: i changed it and its still not working.

Comment: Do you change to this

Comment: Its still  not working...

Comment: app.post('/', function(req,res){
    let data = req.params;
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data)
})

Comment: I am trying from both

Comment: What it  logs when you do the request?

Comment: Im going to put an image in the bottom of the question

Comment: I changed the answer check uaing req.query